# Orbit Slider jQuery and Google Adsense

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense, orbit

I'm trying to implement [Orbit Slider](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider) in my homepage using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/help_support.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/terms_conditions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/privacy_policy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.orbit-1.2.3.min.js"></script>

<!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .timer { display: none !important; }
        div.caption { background:transparent; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000);zoom: 1; }
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#featured').orbit();
    });
</script>
```

This works, but if I add the following code to my page, where I want to show Google Adsense ads, the slider stops loading images in Safari, Chrome and Firefox (for some reason it still works in Opera).

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        google_ad_client = ad_client;
        /* homepage_200x200_1 */
        google_ad_slot = ad_slot;
        google_ad_width = 200;
        google_ad_height = 200;
        //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>
</div>
```

I've found many questions about jQuery conflicts in here and [this useful page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) on the web, but I'm new to javascript and I'm not able to make my actual code work.

Can you please help me fixing my code?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: What does this script is doing
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
Is this the jquery min file? if yes then remove the following script reference <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: I've removed jquery-1.5.1.min.js, but nothing changes :(

Comment: Is there any javascript error? See the error console in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and after doing research I found out that the

> $(window).load(function() {

should be

> $(function() {

I found the answer here http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=253841

Comment: Here I am... I found your solution works!!! Thank you a lot for your help (and for waiting my try ^_^)