# jQuery undefined variable on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm have multiple buttons on teh site and I can't write data atributes into variables.

My html

```
<button id="verzije" data-href="http://example.com/qjzvq6pxk1ru" data-sub="http://example.com/podnapisi/file.txt" data-vers="1">1. verzija</button> 
<button id="verzije" data-href="http://example.com/f/4pXOzy" data-sub="http://example.com/podnapisi/file.txt" data-vers="2">2. verzija</button> 
<button id="verzije" data-href="http://example.com/eo0hn7ajh4j3" data-sub="http://example.com/podnapisi/file.txt" data-vers="3">3. verzija</button>
```

My javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var film = jQuery(this).data('href');
        var pod = jQuery(this).data('sub');
        var capback = jQuery(this).data('cap');
        var verz = jQuery(this).data('vers');
        jQuery.post("http://example.com/filmi.php",
        {
          link: film,
          sub: pod,
          cap: capback,
          vers: verz
        },
        function(data){
          jQuery('#flashplayer').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

This code worked for a while, then i added ads on my site and code stopped working. Is there some other way for this code? I've tried to unbind event listeners of ads and it didn't work. If i turn on my adblock, everything works perfectly, if it's off it doesn't work. Any solution?

NOTE: I have jQuery included!

Comment: (off-topic) it is bad practice to have multiple elements with the same id on a page

Comment: Please could you clarify more " i added ads on my site and code stopped working"?

Comment: Your code is working fine ! Can you check your console ??

Comment: I don't find anything wrong except the same ID provided which considerably a bad practice. I don't get exactly though what is the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have should work, though there are some reports of possible JS conflicting with Google Ads for example. See [here](http://codingforums.com/javascript-frameworks/253841-conflict-between-google-ads-jquery.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073241/orbit-slider-jquery-and-google-adsense). In the cases linked to, it was the `window.onload` vs `(document).ready` event that was re-bound by two functions. 
The second link states your probable answer:

Do

```
$(function() {
```

instead of

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

You should also change the `id`'s though.